# How to configure TSQLConnection with SQLite?

Tags: sqlite, delphi

I chose **Sqlite** as the driver for the **SQLConnection1** component using the Object Inspector.

Whenever I run my **VCL Forms Application** with these codes:

```
procedure TForm6.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  SQLConnection1.Params.Add('Database=C:\test.s3db');
  SQLConnection1.Connected := true;
end;
```

I am getting Debugger Exception Notifications.

> First chance exception at $74FFB727. Exception class EExternalException with message 'External exception C06D007E'. Process Project5.exe (3508)

and

> First chance exception at $00000000. Exception class $C0000005 with message 'access violation at 0x00000000: read of address 0x00000000'. Process Project5.exe (3508)

Comment: You say "After Setting SQLConnection1 driver to Sqlite..." This description would presume a design-time error, but your error messages appear to be run-time. Do you get these exceptions when you click this button?

Comment: Try to move the database file to an other location. Your porgram need admin rights to write to the root of the system drive.

Comment: Oh sorry for my wrong delivery of information.

I am getting those error messages during run-time, I get these exeptions when I execute those lines of code.

I have already edited the post.

@JerryDodge

Comment: Why did you remove so much important information from your question? I even put your screenshot there for you. It's like a whole new question now. That's what we call a "moving target".

Comment: "Note: On Windows, in order to connect to an SQLite database, place the library sqlite3.dll in your system path and verify that sqlite3.dll can be found by your application."

Comment: I wrote you detailed instructions about how to go about debugging this in an answer to the previous version of this q, which you've since deleted.  Did you try following them?  Meanwhile, -1.

Comment: @MartynA, Sorry but it didn't work for me :-(

Comment: @ValMarinov I want to mark your comment as an answer for my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According [Deploying dbExpress Database Applications](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE8/en/Deploying_dbExpress_Database_Applications)

and [Tutorial: Connecting to a SQLite Database from a VCL Application](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE8/en/Tutorial:_Connecting_to_a_SQLite_Database_from_a_VCL_Application)

> On Windows, in order to connect to an SQLite database, place the
> library sqlite3.dll in your system path and verify that sqlite3.dll
> can be found by your application.
>
> On Windows 32-bit: C:\Windows\System32
>
> On Windows 64-bit: C:\Windows\SysWOW64

Оf course the file `sqlite3.dll` may be in the folder where is the executable file.

Answer (score 0):

install **SQLite ODBC Driver**, and use `adoconnection` to connect.
connectionstring like `"DRIVER=SQLite3 ODBC Driver;Database=c:\test\test.db;LongNames=0;Timeout=1000;NoTXN=0;SyncPragma=NORMAL;StepAPI=0;"`

Comment: The question is about `DBExpress` not for `ADO`

Answer (score 0):

In RAD Studio 10.2, using `SQLConnection1.LoginPrompt := false` solved the issue.

```
ConStr := 'Database=' + GetCurrentDir + '\nhl.s3db';
SQLConnection1.LoginPrompt := false;
SQLConnection1.Params.Add(ConStr);
SQLConnection1.Connected := true;
```